# How to manage who I'm following on Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

Currently I'm following almost 2k users on Twitter, I wish to review my followings and remove some of them, but it's very time consuming to check all of those one by one!

Basically I need to unfollow these users:

1. Who are not active anymore and have no tweets in last 2 month.
2. Who unfollowed me.
3. Users that appears that their account got hacked, and who send spammy DMs.

It would be very useful if I could have a list to see users profile, website, their last tweet and an unfollow button, all next to each other. is there any trustworthy ready-to-use application available or can I make something with Twitter API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Friend or Follow](http://friendorfollow.com/) is a pretty good option here. The web app allows you to filter all those that you follow (for free), and sort by:

- Follow/Followers Ratio (which will help determine spambots)
- Last Tweet (to determine inactive users)
- And users who do not follow you back

Comment: the free version of the app doesn't provide the interesting features (Follow/Followers Ratio, Last Tweet) & hardly anything else that is useful

Comment: @mvark - um, yes it does.

Comment: I prefer this one, because it doesn't ask me to connect my account to it, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[ManageFlitter](http://manageflitter.com) can do some of that.

1. Inactive people who have not tweeted anything for 30 days
2. People you follow who don't follow you

Plus a bunch of other options, although some of them require a Pro account. Once you find the accounts it's easy to remove them in bulk.

Comment: I haven't tried this one yet, because I'm not comfortable with authorizing it for my account, I should first try it with an alt account, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try Twitter Lists, It is a good feature that they have added. It is  a way by which you can have separate lists (groups) based on your choice.